# Directive not binding to model in controller surrounding it Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Directive not binding to model in controller surrounding it. I have a directive WYSIWYG and it is not binding to the model of the the enclosing controller.

[The Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uAOkmQ?p=preview)

```
my view
    <span ng-controller="journalQuickController">
    <wysiwyg textarea-id="queshtion" textarea-class="form-control"  textarea-height="40px" textarea-name="textareaQuestion" textarea-required ng-model="journal.name" enable-bootstrap-title="false"></wysiwyg>

    </span>
```

This is my controller

```
crossfitApp.controller('journalQuickController', ['$scope', '$fileUploader', function ($scope,$fileUploader) {
            uiVars ={}; 

            submitted= false; 
            $scope.journal ={name:" default data here "};
    }]);  




directive source code:


 '<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm wysiwyg-btn-group-margin" >' +
            '<button ng-show="!isLink" tabindex="-1" title="Link" type="button" unselectable="on" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="createLink()"><i class="fa icon-link" ></i> </button>' +
            '<button ng-show="isLink" tabindex="-1" title="Unlink" type="button" unselectable="on" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="format(\'unlink\')"><i class="fa icon-link2"></i> </button>' +
            '<button title="Image" tabindex="-1" type="button" unselectable="on" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="insertImage()"><i class="fa icon-image4"></i> </button>' +

          '</div>' +

            '<div id="{{textareaId}}" style="resize:vertical;height:{{textareaHeight || \'80px\'}}; overflow:auto" contentEditable="true" class="{{textareaClass}} wysiwyg-textarea" rows="{{textareaRows}}" name="{{textareaName}}" required="{{textareaRequired}}" placeholder="{{textareaPlaceholder}}" ng-model="value"></div>' +
          '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
      value: '^ngModel',
      textareaHeight: '@textareaHeight',
      textareaName: '@textareaName',
      textareaPlaceholder: '@textareaPlaceholder',
      textareaClass: '@textareaClass',
      textareaRequired: '@textareaRequired',
      textareaId: '@textareaId'
    },
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
```

Comment: Hey , please post only the relevant code , not all of your code, so we be able to help

Comment: Added more information. How to I bind this directive to an external model?

Comment: If you want the model value, you should interact with the ngModelController. (The line with value: '^ngModel' is not helping). Are you making a call to ngModelController in the link function?